# How to convert a blob url of audio to normal url for downloading files in react?

Tags: reactjs, blob

I used a voice recorder in my application, the voice data contains a blobUrl, that I want to send that url to server for downloading it, but it is not a normal url. is there any way to convert my blob url of audio to a normal url?
`blob:http://localhost:3001/dfafdba3-24f4-4f36-b9d8-13f4d9634acc`

Answer (score 0):

this might be what you're looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71885435/11483674

In summary: you extract the data from your browser's blobUrl, make a file out of that and send it over a request to your backend.